# Input shows the previous value for a while

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After successfull patch method triggered by onBlur, input shows the previous value for a fraction of a second, and then changes to the new one retrieved from the server. This is probably caused by useEffect, which can potentially return the previous value. I don't know how to fix it, I tried with ChatGPT and applied different combinations of hooks and it didn't do anything. I am not sure if I have diagnosed the problem correctly.

How to make the input not show the previous value?

[image]

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export const TableNumberInput = ({
  cell,
  mutate,
  ...restProps
}: {
  cell: unknown;
  mutate: unknown;
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(parseFloat(cell.getValue()));
  }, [cell.getValue()]);

  const [value, setValue] = useState(parseFloat(cell.getValue()));

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleBlur = (event) => {
    const num = eval(event.target.value);
    const rounded_num = Math.round(num * 100) / 100;

    if (value !== parseFloat(cell.getValue())) {
      mutate(
        {
          id: cell.row.original.id.toString(),
          data: { [cell.column.id]: rounded_num },
        },
        {
          onError: () => {
            inputRef.current.select();
            inputRef.current.focus();
          },
          onSuccess: () => {},
        }
      );
    }
    setValue(parseFloat(cell.getValue()));
  };

  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      precision={2}
      onBlur={(event) => handleBlur(event)}
      {...restProps}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Definetly It will not change until it get response from the server. So, until the response come, you are going to see the previous value. For better UX, I would suggest use a small loader on the input field only, that shows that value is coming. Also, during that time, make your input field blur or as it suits you from design perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems to be with the order of your state update and the `async` operation. When the `handleBlur` function is called, the `setValue` hook is being called before the server operation is completed.

The solution would be to move `setValue(parseFloat(cell.getValue()));` to onSuccess callback in your mutate function.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export const TableNumberInput = ({
  cell,
  mutate,
  ...restProps
}: {
  cell: unknown;
  mutate: unknown;
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(parseFloat(cell.getValue()));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(parseFloat(cell.getValue()));
  }, [cell.getValue()]);

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleBlur = (event) => {
    const num = eval(event.target.value);
    const rounded_num = Math.round(num * 100) / 100;

    if (value !== parseFloat(cell.getValue())) {
      mutate(
        {
          id: cell.row.original.id.toString(),
          data: { [cell.column.id]: rounded_num },
        },
        {
          onError: () => {
            inputRef.current.select();
            inputRef.current.focus();
          },
          onSuccess: () => {
            // Set value after successful server operation
            setValue(parseFloat(cell.getValue()));
          },
        }
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      precision={2}
      onBlur={(event) => handleBlur(event)}
      {...restProps}
    />
  );
};
```

**Oh and also `eval()` bad idea from a security perspective.**

Comment: I applied your suggestion however the problem still occurs. The incorrect value appears as if for a shorter time, but it still appears.  I added a gif that shows the problem.

Comment: @skelaw Yes it will occur. Because you are updating the field on server response. So, response will take time.